# How to create a lattice/grid with connected lines, but also border/shadow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I need to create a lattice/grid overlay for a photo editor UI. The lines of the grid itself should be white, and "interconnected" - eg they don't visibly overlap each other. However, the *entire grid* needs to either have a border of 1px, or a shadow.

Here's an example:

[image]

Any ideas how this can be achieved? Ideally I'd like a solution I can position absolutely over the image itself.

Although it probably makes little difference, this is for a React Native project.

Comment: might want to look at `display: grid` or `table` and go from there

Comment: @A.Lau In that case, RN does impact this. Only display:flex is available, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps you out. I have setup a base using `grid` layout. Please check if it is fine.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100px;
}
.grid-item {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 10px -10px 15px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, `display: grid` does not work on React Native.

Comment: Ok, i think flex will work out the. I will update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you should use something like [react-native-shadow](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow) package.

You can achieve shadow on android only via `elevation` style attribute, which does not give an opportunity to control shadow offset and radius.

Comment: This is not even close to an answer, and should have been left as a comment. I don't see how that package is going to help me. And yes, I'm aware of `elevation` on Android.